# Как перевернуть в C# текст чтобы было "У лукоморья дуб зеленый" стало "зеленый дуб лукоморья У"?

Tags: c#

я начинающий падаван которому нужна помощь от всемогущих джедаев.

Comment: Задача непонятна. Вы либо на вход получаете строку и начинаете разбивать её по пробелам, либо получаете уже разбитый текст. В заголовке одно, в тексте другое. Определитесь хотя бы с форматом данных на входе и на выходе: что есть, что нужно получить.

Comment: Вообще задание такое: Дан текст, содержащий от 1 до 30 слов, в каждом из которых от 1 до 5 строчных латинских букв; между соседними словами − запятая, за последним словом − точка. Вывести слова текста, упорядочив их по убыванию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вас есть уже массив отдельных слов, то тогда используйте метод `Reverse()`. :

```
var reversedLines = string.Join(' ', lines.Reverse());
Console.WriteLine(reversedLines);
```

Если нужно получить другой результат, то опишите подробнее, что на входе и на выходе.

**UPD.** С учетом уточненных условий задачи (валидацию не писал, потому что вопрос был именно в том, как перевернуть слова текста):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var text = "john,have,some,question,for,you.";
    Console.WriteLine($"Before: {text}");

    text = text.Remove(text.Length - 1); // Удаляем точку, чтобы при сплите не входила в последнее слово
    var words = text.Split(',');
    var reversedText = string.Join(' ', words.Reverse());

    Console.WriteLine($"After : {reversedText}");
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое я не знал что Reverse() можно применять к String().

Comment: @BatrFeed Reverse в данном случае применяется не к string, а к `string[]`

Comment: Чуть позже перепишу решение задачи в связи с обновленным условием

Answer (score 3):

Вот решение:  за основу взято

> У лукоморья дуб зеленый

на выходе получаем

> зеленый лукоморья дуб У

вот как работает :

```
string row = "У лукоморья дуб зеленый";
string s =  WordsCange(row, "зеленый", 0);
```

в предложении 4 слова значит 4 позиции на которые можно поставить слово

---

Сам метод:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Метод меняет слова местами
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="row"> строка с исходным текстом </param>
        /// <param name="word">слово которое хотим поменять местами</param>
        /// <param name="pos">позиция на которую ставим слово начинается с 0 </param>
        /// <returns>возвращает String с измененной строкой</returns>
        string WordsCange(string row, string word, int pos)
        {
            var splitedRow = row.Split(' ');

            int index = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < splitedRow.Length; i++)
            {
                if (splitedRow[i] == word)
                {
                    index = i;
                }
            }

            string tmp = splitedRow[pos];
            splitedRow[pos] = word;

            splitedRow[index] = tmp;

            string newRow = "";
            foreach (var curnetword in splitedRow)
            {
                newRow += curnetword + " ";
            }

            return newRow;
        }
```

Comment: Самое эталонное решение для учебной задачи, имху, как раз такое и ожидают преподаватели.

Answer (score 2):

Использйте стэк. Первый пришел, последний вышел. Пример реализации с https://docs.microsoft.com/

```
public static void Main()  {

  // Создание и наполнение.
  Stack myStack = new Stack();
  myStack.Push("Hello");
  myStack.Push("World");
  myStack.Push("!");

  // Вывод.
  PrintValues( myStack ); }



public static void PrintValues( IEnumerable myCollection )  {
      foreach ( Object obj in myCollection )
         Console.Write( "    {0}", obj );
      Console.WriteLine();
   }
```

Если у Вас уже есть набор слов массивом, просто вставьте все значения туда, если у Вас все одной строкой - то используйте string.Split чтобы разделить все.

```
var collection = myString.Split(' ');
```

Comment: Вы можете улучшить свой ответ, если будете использовать Generic-реализацию стека (`var myStack = new Stack<string>()`)